# Finding the limit $\lim_{n\to ∞}$ $\frac {\sqrt{n} + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt{2 n + 1}}$

Tags: limits

I know that $\lim_{n\to ∞}$ $\frac {\sqrt{n} + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt{2 n + 1}} = \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}$

but i don't really follow the steps in between.

Anyone keen on helping out? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "but i don't really follow the steps in between." Which steps? Are we supposed to guess them?

Comment: Divide top and bottom of the LHS by $\sqrt{n}$,

Comment: The steps needed to arrive to the answer. Some hints, if anybody had a clue. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
  \frac {\sqrt{n} + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt{2 n + 1}} &= \sqrt\frac {n}
  {2n+1} + \sqrt\frac {n^{2/3}}{2n+1} + \sqrt\frac {n^{1/2}}{2n+1}\\
  &= \sqrt\frac {1}{2+\frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt\frac {\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}}{2+\frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt\frac {\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}}{2+\frac{1}{n}} 
\end{align*}

which leads to, since $n \mapsto n^{q}$ is continuos for all $q > 0\colon$

\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac {\sqrt{n} + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt{2 n + 1}} &= \sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac {1}{2+\frac{1}{n}}} + \sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac {\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}}{2+\frac{1}{n}}} + \sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac {\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}}{2+\frac{1}{n}}}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac 1 2}\; = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Put $n=m^{12}$
and  compute

$$\lim_{m\to +\infty}\frac{m^{6}+m^4+m^3}{m^6 \sqrt{2} }\sqrt{\frac{ 2  }{ 2+m^{-12}  }}$$

which gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Also, this isn't really much of a "hint" as it is a full solution,

Comment: i made the correction

Comment: My mistake on the rollback, although ugly, you are correct to have included that squareroot on the side to account for the fact that it was a $\sqrt{2n+1}$ instead of a $\sqrt{2n}$

Comment: That is pretty elegant.

Comment: @Obriareos Thanks a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use *equivalents*:

$\sqrt n+\sqrt[3]n+\sqrt[4]n\sim_\infty \sqrt n$, so
$$\frac{\sqrt n+\sqrt[3]n+\sqrt[4]n}{\sqrt{2n}}\sim_\infty \frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{2n}}=\frac1{\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: Very good style. When it comes to the asymptotic behaviour the Landau notation (or asymptotic equivalence) should always be used.

Answer (score 1):

The standard (?) technique with rational functions involving radicals and/or polynomials for limits to infinity: Divide the top and bottom by something simple:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[4]x}{\sqrt{2x+1}}&=\frac{x^{1/2}+x^{1/3}+x^{1/4}}{(2x+1)^{1/2}}\\&=\frac{1+\frac1{x^{1/6}}+\frac1{x^{1/4}}}{(2+\frac1x)^{1/2}}\\&\to\frac{1+0+0}{(2+0)^{1/2}}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{align}$$